# How to find and replace begin tag and end tags in an html string using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find and replace begin tag and end tags in an html string using javascript/jquery

for example

```
var myString = "<span> Hello john</span><div> John likes to play guitar </div> <div style="color:Blue;font-weight:bold" class='quotes'>Anna likes to arrange flowers
        </div>";
```

I need to find the "div" tag and replace with other html tag like "p" tag/ "span" tag

Resulting html string after replace "div" tag to "p" tag

```
var replacestring="<span> Hello john</span><p> John likes to play guitar </p> <p style="color:Blue;font-weight:bold" class='quotes'>Anna  likes to arrange flowers
            </p>";
```

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript with regular expression:

```
myString = myString.replace(/<(\/)?div[^>]*>/g, '<$1p>');
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xScVa/).

=== UPDATE ===

```
myString = myString.replace(/<(\/)?div([^>]*)>/g, '<$1p$2>');
```

[jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/xScVa/1/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Your regular expression method is good , but if we use this, the attributes of the tags are lost. We need to keep all the attributes and style while using this. So it needs a modification

Comment: How do I modify the second fiddle in case I need to replace div tags with a particular classname  ?

Answer (score 4):

```
myString = $('<div />').html(myString).find('div').replaceWith(function() {
    var p = $('<p />');
    p.html($(this).html());
    $.each(this.attributes, function(index, attr) {
        p.attr(attr.name, attr.value);  
    });
    return p;
}).end().html();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t44sA/).

Comment: This needs JQuery!

Comment: The question is tagged with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Trying something with jQuery, however, I am not sure if it is any better than what alex suggested.

```
var $replaceString=$(replaceString);

$("div",$replaceString).each(
    function()
    {
        var $p=$(document.createElement('p')).html($(this).html());
        //add code to add any attribute that you want to be copied over.
        $(this).after($p);
        $(this).remove();
    }
);
```